# How to synchronize two methods

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I have following code for a chat server application in Java -

```
public synchronized List<ChatMessage> getMessages(int messageNumber) {
    return messages.subList(messageNumber + 1, messages.size());
}

public synchronized int addMessage(ChatMessage c) {
    messages.add(c);
    return messages.size()-1;
}
```

I have following test code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ChatRoom c = new ChatRoom();
    Thread user1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                c.addMessage(new ChatMessage());
                c.getMessages(0);
            }
        }
    });
    Thread user2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                c.addMessage(new ChatMessage());
                c.getMessages(0).size();
            }
        }
    });
    user1.start();
    user2.start();
}
```

I am getting a ConcurrentModificationException.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How is this possible?

Your `getMessages` method just returns a *view* on the original list. It doesn't create a *copy* of the list. So one thread is using a view on the list while another modifies the list - at that point, you get the exception.

From the docs for [`List.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve here, but fundamentally you can't use `subList` to magically create a thread-safe list :)

Comment: Jon skeet answered my question! :-O The problem just solved itself. :-)

Comment: But my confusion is how could one thread iterate over view i.e. call getMessages() when another is modifying it, since both getMessages() and addMessage() are synchronized. Why didn't synchronization happen at method level?

Comment: @MonikaMichael: You're calling `size()` on the *result* of the synchronization - that's the problem. You create the sublist in one thread, release the lock, the other thread acquires the lock, calls `add()` on the underlying list (which invalidates the view) and then you call `size()` in the first thread.

Comment: Could you also please answer this question :-( - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809100/how-to-use-same-connection-for-two-queries-in-spring

Comment: Could you suggest a solution to this then? I'll be writing two REST services exposing these methods. Not really sure how to synchronize this the best way.

Comment: @MonikaMichael: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. You should probably be looking at one of the concurrent lists though...

Comment: Well I'm trying to write a chat server application. The addMessage service should not be called if getMessage is currently executing and vice versa. Anyway thanks for your help, it cleared up a lot of things.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please consider writing a Java in Depth book. I'll buy the first 5 copies. I promise. :-)

Comment: @MonikaMichael: Have you read Effective Java (preferably the 2nd edition)? Josh Bloch writes *much* better than I do :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to create a combined method

```
public synchronized int addMessageAndGetCount(ChatMessage c) {
    messages.add(c);
    return messages.size();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    final ChatRoom c = new ChatRoom();
    final Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                c.addMessageAndGetCount(new ChatMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner).start();
    new Thread(runner).start();
}
```

You cannot safely return a list or a subList from a synchronized block. You can return a copy but all you need is the size.

Comment: Well isn't that already happening in the addMessage() method. I was calling size() on getMessages() as a test case. That isn't the only processing requirement.

Comment: You can combine the work you need synchronized into a method and never return the original collection. BTW: A test case tests its results and should fail if the code is incorrect. I suggest you start by writing a failing test and then fixing the code so the test passes. A test which never fails isn't useful (except as an example of course)