# Configure transaction in Spring 4.1.5 without XML

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

I'm writing application which connects with Oracle Database. I call function from DB which inserts new records to table. And after this callback I can decide what I want to do: commit or rollback.

Unfortunalety I'm new in Spring, so I have problems with configuration. And what's more I want to make this configuration in Java class, not in XML. And here I need your help.

**UPDATED CODE:**

**ApplicationConfig code:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("hr")
@PropertySource({"classpath:jdbc.properties", "classpath:functions.properties", "classpath:procedures.properties"})
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="txName")
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

I have Dao and Service, where both implements proper interface.

**Service implementation:**

```
@Service
public class HumanResourcesServiceImpl implements HumanResourcesService {

    @Autowired
    private HumanResourcesDao hrDao;

    @Override
    public String generateData(int rowsNumber) {
        return hrDao.generateData(rowsNumber);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional("txName")
    public void shouldCommit(boolean doCommit, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        hrDao.shouldCommit(doCommit, connection);
    }
}
```

**Dao implementation:**

```
@Repository
public class HumanResourcesDaoImpl implements HumanResourcesDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall generateData;

    @Autowired
    public HumanResourcesDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, Environment env) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        generateData = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName(env.getProperty("procedure.generateData"));
    }

    @Override
    public String generateData(int rowsNumber) {
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("i_rowsNumber", rowsNumber);
        Map<String, Object> m = generateData.execute(params);
        return (String) m.get("o_execution_time");
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional("txName")
    public void shouldCommit(boolean doCommit, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        if(doCommit) {
            connection.commit();
        } else {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class code:

```
public class Main extends Application implements Initializable {
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);

        hrService = context.getBean(HumanResourcesService.class);

        BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource)context.getBean("dataSource");
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();

        //do something and call
        //hrService.generateData
        //do something and call
        //hrService.shouldCommit(true, connection);
        //which commit or rollback generated data from previoues callback
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think that the problem is with connection, because this statement:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

creates new connection, so then there is nothing to commit or rollback. But still I can't figure why this doesn't work properly. No errors, no new records...
What is wierd, is that when I debuged **connection.commit();** I found out that in DelegatingConnection.java, parameter **this** has proper connection, but there is something like:

```
_conn.commit();
```

and **_conn** has different connection. Why?

Should I in some way synchronize connection for those 2 methods or what? Or this is only one connection? To be honest, I'm not sure how it works exactly. One connection and all callbacks to stored procedures are in this connection or maybe with each callback new connection is created?

Real question is **how to commit or rollback data from previous callback which do insert into table?**

Comment: what is your question?  what is the issue?

Comment: Problem is that I can't configure it properly... Even with guides below that isn't working...

Comment: The question should be: how to commit or rollback data from previous callback which do insert into table.

Comment: Which data are you expecting in your DB?!!

Comment: These from generate data method. I call a procedure from DB which inserts data to the table. That's it. After that, I would like to decide if they should be commit or rollback.

Comment: you don't need to commit or rollback manually. Spring does this for you. You should never have access to the underlying connection.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to annotate the method with `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public void myBeanMethod() {
    ...
    if (!doCommit)
        throw new IllegalStateException(); // any unchecked will do
}
```

and spring will roll all database changes back.

Remember to add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your spring application/main class

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it didn't work for me :( I said more about it in @qtips answer, please look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Transactional` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` to setup transactions without using the XML configuration. In short, annotate the methods/classes you want to have transactions with `@Transactional`. To setup the transactional management you use the `@EnableTransactionManagement` inside your `@Configuration`.

See Springs [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations) for example on how to use both. The `@EnableTransactionManagement` is detailed in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) but should match the XML configuration.

*UPDATE*

The problem is that you are mixing raw JDBC calls (java.sql.Connection) with Spring JDBC. When you execute your `SimpleJdbcCall`, Spring creates a new `Connection`. This is not the same `Connection` as the one you later try to commit. Hence, nothing happens when you perform the commit. I tried to somehow get the connection that the `SimpleJdbcCall` uses, but could not find any easy way.

To test this I tried the following (I did not use `params`):

```
@Override
public String generateData(int rowsNumber) {
    //HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    //params.put("i_rowsNumber", rowsNumber);
    //Map<String, Object> m = generateData.execute(params);

     Connection targetConnection = DataSourceUtils.getTargetConnection(generateData.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection());
     System.out.println(targetConnection.prepareCall((generateData.getCallString())).execute());
  targetConnection.commit();

    return (String) m.get("o_execution_time");
}
```

If I don't save the targetConnection, and instead try to get the connection again by calling `DataSourceUtils.getTargetConnection()` when committing, nothing happens. Thus, you must commit on the same connection that you perform the statement on. This does not seem to be easy, nor the proper way.

The solution is to drop the `java.sql.Connection.commit()` call. Instead, you use Spring Transactions completly.  If you use `@Transaction` on the method that performs database call, Spring will automatically commit when the method has finished. If the method body experiences any Exception (even outside the actual database call) it will automatically rollback. In other words, this should suffice for normal Transaction management.

However, if you are doing batch processing, and wish to have more control over your transactions with commits and rollbacks, you can still use Spring. To programatically control transactions with Spring, you can use `TransactionTemplate` which have commit and rollback methods. Don't have time to give you proper samples, but may do so in later days if you are still stuck ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately it didn't work... 
I add annotaion EnableTransactionManagement in ApplicationConfig class and annotaion Transactional in my dao method, but then I get an error:
"No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined"

So I add Transactional also in the service method, then I get the same error.

I googled the error and found that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806857/3474610) and then I don't have errors, but it doesn't work. I get info in console "Commit", but I don't see new records in DB table.

Comment: Are you somehow accidently overwriting the transaction setup with a xml context? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491748/spring-jdbc-declarative-transactions-created-but-not-doing-anything. You can also try to turn on debug log to see what happens. How do you do you test your code? I also read something about Unit tests rolling back by default (but then you should get some message about it). Edit your question with debug log and how you test so the others can help ;)

Comment: No, I don't overwrite it, I don't even use xml in my app. Everything based on Java classes. I also don't use Unit test. I've updated my question, but I don't know how to setup debug log.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.saat")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:resources/db.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryBean")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.saat");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql",env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);
        return factoryBean;
    }


    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpatransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpatransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return jpatransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what this does, how it solves the OP's problem, how it is different from existing answers. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers)