# I can persist data through the test but not through the app. aop problems

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite, spring-mvc

I've been spending two days in trying to resolve a weird problem. I'm working in a MVC Spring App and when I run the following test....

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/persistence-beans.xml")
public class UserDaoTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        int size = userDao.list().size();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("omar");
        userDao.add(user);

        List<User> users = userDao.list();

        System.out.println("users size: " + users.size());

        // list should have one more employee now
        assertTrue (size < users.size());
    }
}
```

I see the result in the data base and all it's ok. But, when I call a controller and use the same Dao (userDao) to create an user, the app does not persist the user and do not throw any error. The only thing that comes to my mind is that there is a problem with the transaction annotation from Spring in the part of the servlet-context.xml. I can believe that in the test case work but not in app flow!
Please, I need to get out from this problem!!!!

------ Interface Dao --------

```
public interface GenericDao<E, K> {

    void add(E entity);

    void update(E entity);

    void remove(E entity);

    E find(K key);

    List<E> list();
}

public interface UserDao extends GenericDao<User, Long>{

}
```

---

```
package com.tutorial.dao.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.tutorial.dao.GenericDao;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public class GenericDaoJPAImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K>{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    protected Class<E> daoType;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoJPAImpl() {
        daoType = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void add(E entity) {
        em().persist(entity);
    }

    public EntityManager em() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E entity) {
        em().merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        em().remove(em().merge(entity));
    }

    @Override
    public E find(K key) {
        return (E) em().find(daoType, key);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> list() {

        List<E> list = null;

        TypedQuery<E> query = em().createQuery("select o from "
                + daoType.getSimpleName() + " o",
                daoType);

        list = query.getResultList();
        return list;

    }

}


@Repository("UserDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoJPAImpl<User, Long> implements UserDao{
}
```

-------- Service Layer -----------

```
@Service("calculatorService")
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements CalculatorService{

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

   @Override 
    public void createUser(User user) {
        userDao.add(user);
    }

}
```

---------- Controller --------------

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/calculate")
public class CalculatorController {

@Autowired
    private CalculatorService calculatorService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(User user){

        calculatorService.createUser(user);

        return "session";
    }
}
```

------- Persistence Beans ---------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- we can use annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />  

    <!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.dao.impl" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:properties/database.properties"/>

   <!-- data source for our database -->
    <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
   </bean>

   <!-- EntityManagerFactoryBean -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---------------------- Servlet Context -----------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />   

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

<!--All beans are scanned here, except the Repository because they are scanned in persistence-beans.xml-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.*" >
       <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

</beans:beans>
```

----------------------- WEB XML --------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        classpath:persistence-beans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>calculator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>calculator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The link of this project is the next: https://github.com/igiagante/calculator

Feel free to download to prove what's going on :) Thanks you!!!

Comment: Looking at your spring xml files, I see that you are building all beans but the repository implementations in the servlet app context, and only the repository implementations and beans located in persistence-beans.xml in root app context. Can you try modifying that such as only the controller beans are built in the servlet app contrxt, and the rest of the beans (services, repositories, infrastructure) in the root context?

Comment: Luciano, I tried what you recommend but it's still not working. I hate when these things happens. A dorf sun of the bitch is inside of the app and maybe it is called AOP. If I cannot resolve this for tomorrow, I'll have to change Spring MVC for other. :(

Comment: I've launched your project on mysql and all works fine. But I have no method CalculatorService.createUser(User user). CalculatorService.createSession(User user) instead. Do I have correct version of you application?

Comment: Yes. You have the correct version. I changed CalculatorService.createSession(User user) by CalculatorService.createUser(User user) to do it more easy to understand. At the moment I'm focusing on persisting data and that's way I've been trying to persist an user. I did not try with mysql because the challenge is to use sqlite, which gave me a lot of headache.

Comment: I tried this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161445/spring-transactional-annotation-not-working-with-auto-wiring but it didn't work.

Comment: in persistence-beans.xml you declare base-package for component scan "com.tutorial.dao.impl", but the service is not there. try using a more generic package, like "com.tutorial" to see if it works. Personally I don't use any attributes for @Transactional annotation, and use it at method level instead of class level. Also I don't specify name of the service bean. I don't think it's related to the problem but you can try it

Comment: This configuration is inside of the servlet-context.xml file. I'm using two context's files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed  for your CalculatorServiceImpl. While your dispatcher-servlet.xml does.

Have a try that adding

```
<context:component-scan base-package="where your service is"/>
```

in your root application context and remove unnecessary component-scan in your dispatcher-servlet.

Comment: I did not forget CalculatorService Bean. If you download the project you will see that this beans is scanned by Spring and is mapped to CalculatorServiceImpl. Luciano recommend to me the same what you say and it continues without working.

Comment: hmmm... I took a look at your project. But I didn't find where the service is scanned(I found @ Service("calculatorService") only), maybe I'm not familiar with the package structure. Could you point it out on your question?

Comment: Ready. I'm trying with MySQL and I am having the same problem, but with the difference that when I run the app, I received the next Exception... java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calculate. I added the mysql connector dependency and the jar is. So, I smell that something wrong in the configuration files is still there.